# How does one expose a VB.NET System.Data class in a COM Wrapper?

Tags: vb.net, com, wrapper

How does one expose a System.Data class in a COM Wrapper? I have followed the tutorial here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7587/Exposing-COM-interfaces-of-a-NET-class-library-for. Which works beautify to allow a VB6 program to access .NET only DLLs, but I want to pass a `System.Data.DataRow` to the VB6 program for manipulation. The ``DataRow class isn't being exposed to COM and shows up as an `Unknown` data type in the references. Is there a way to expose/implement/extend a `DataRow` to be visible to a COM program?

Comment: It should be simple enough to expose a wrapper (*around* the non-exposed DataRow) - only include the domain-relevant operations and proxy through.

Comment: how do I wrap a system class?

Comment: Create a new type, accepting the wrapped object as a constructor parameter. Store it as a private instance variable. Then write methods to access (read, update) the wrapped object. The outside container (the new type) is what is exposed to COM. It can still access the wrapped object normally without exposing it directly.

Comment: Sorry I haven't written in vb in like 15 years, could you provide an example? I'm trying to pass a DataRow so that I can update fields, not sure if I can pass an array or ItemArray to update them.

Comment: (vb.net I mean)